# JavaScript question about: What does "?." means after a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

What does "?." means after a function?
As after i

`const user = () => { query.fetch(data); // anything here}`
but we are getting to access it like user?.name...
what does ?. means

const user = () => { query.fetch(data); // anything here}

Comment: It's the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optional chaining (?.) operator accesses an object's property or calls a function. If the object accessed or function called is undefined or null, it returns undefined instead of throwing an error.